# Google maps Javascript API not working when deployed to device

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have this code, it runs fine on the browser but when i deploy it to my android device, it doesn't work. The code is meant to get my current location, then give me directions to a specified location. Any help? Thanks in advance.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
        <title>Rotrack</title>
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="js/index.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).bind('mobileinit',function(){
                $.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false;
                $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
                $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
            });
        </script> 
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&language=en"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var map,
                currentPosition,
                directionsDisplay, 
                directionsService;

            function initialize(lat, lon)
            {
                directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(); 
                directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

                currentPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);

                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
                   zoom: 20,
                   center: currentPosition,
                   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                 });

                directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

                 var currentPositionMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: currentPosition,
                    map: map,
                    title: "Current position"
                });

                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                google.maps.event.addListener(currentPositionMarker, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow.setContent("Current position: latitude: " + lat +" longitude: " + lon);
                    infowindow.open(map, currentPositionMarker);
                });
            }

            function locError(error) {
                // initialize map with a static predefined latitude, longitude
               initialize(59.3426606750, 18.0736160278);
            }

            function locSuccess(position) {
                initialize(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            }

            function calculateRoute() {
                var targetDestination = $("#target-dest").val();
                if (currentPosition && currentPosition != '' && targetDestination && targetDestination != '') {
                    var request = {
                        origin:currentPosition, 
                        destination:targetDestination,
                        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode["DRIVING"]
                    };

                    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                            directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directions"));
                            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response); 

                            /*
                                var myRoute = response.routes[0].legs[0];
                                for (var i = 0; i < myRoute.steps.length; i++) {
                                    alert(myRoute.steps[i].instructions);
                                }
                            */
                            $("#results").show();
                        }
                        else {
                            $("#results").hide();
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $("#results").hide();
                }
            }

            $(document).live("pagebeforeshow", "#map_page", function() {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locSuccess, locError);
            });

            $(document).on('click', '#directions-button', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                calculateRoute();
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="basic-map" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1><a data-ajax="false" href="/">Rotrack</a></h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">   
                <div class="ui-bar-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow" style="padding:1em;">
                    <div id="map_canvas" style="height:350px;"></div>
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="target-dest">Target Destination:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="target-dest" id="target-dest" value=""  />
                </div>
                <a href="#" id="directions-button" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">Get Directions</a>
                <div id="results" style="display:none;">
                    <div id="directions"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is too vague.

Comment: I think i stated clearly what the code is meant to do (what it actually does on the browser), it doesn't do any of that on the device, i don't get an error either.

Answer (score 0):

Use a cordova plugin for google maps like https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps.

It will ensure that Google Map API functions will only be called once all device features have been enabled (GPS access enabled?) and once the device is ready (check cordova onDeviceReady event).

Comment: I just added the plugin now with my key too, it still wont work. Will the plugin work with my code (the sample i gave) because there's no example on the `cordova-plugin-googlemaps` git.

Comment: Do you have cordova-plugin-geolocation installed? Moreover, <access origin="*"/> or  <access origin="http://maps.google.com" />. has to be set correctly. Also the cordova-plugin-whitelist should be installed and configured. Do you have any errors shown in the console while running the app?

Comment: I have all that installed, for some reason, when i remove `<script src="cordova.js"></script>` it works fine. And no, i don't get any errors on the console.

Answer (score -1):

GPS needs to be enabled in your device for this to work.